# getting run time 13 error in vba how to fix this

Tags: excel, vba

I'm actually trying to code the sumproduct VBA script but I'm getting the runtime 13 error...

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sample_sumpro()

Dim cal_date, nxt_date As Date

cal_date = #12/30/2016#

nxt_date = cal_date + 1

Dim name As String, ws As Sheets

name = "Kawale, Amar"

Dim dm_daily As String

With Sheets(1)
dm_daily = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((Columns(16)=name)*Columns(4)>=cal_date)*Columns(4)<nxt_date))")
End With

MsgBox dm_daily

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment to another answer, you say that you are actually trying to do a count with two criteria (or three criteria according to the question).  That is better achieved with Excel's `CountIfs` function, which can be coded in VBA using something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sample_sumpro()
    Dim cal_date As Date, nxt_date As Date
    Dim name As String
    Dim dm_daily As String

    cal_date = #12/30/2016#
    nxt_date = cal_date + 1
    name = "Kawale, Amar"

    With Sheets(1)
        dm_daily = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(16), name, _
                                                          .Columns(4), ">=" & CDbl(cal_date), _
                                                          .Columns(4), "<" & CDbl(nxt_date))
    End With
    MsgBox dm_daily
End Sub
```

Comment: hey @YowE3K... can you tell the how to modify the above code to count with 4 criteria... When doing a modification, getting an error ...

Comment: @Amar To use 4 criteria, just add two more parameters to the `CountIfs` function - the range to look at, and the value to look for.

Comment: yup, your are right .. I tried but the bracket closure might be misplaced that's what it didn't work so did I ask. It may work... let me try first. thank you again.. :)

Comment: @Amar You need to change `...  .Columns(4), "<" & CDbl(nxt_date))` to `...  .Columns(4), "<" & CDbl(nxt_date), new_search_column, new_search_value)`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you're trying to do, but if (just a guess) you're trying to evaluate the `SUMPRODUCT` of columns 14 and 15, you might want to try this:

```
Sub TestEvaluate()

Dim ws As Worksheet, x As String

Set ws = Worksheets(2)
x = Evaluate("sumproduct(" & ws.Columns(14).Address & "," & ws.Columns(15).Address & ")")
MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: hey thank you for your response...

but actually I am trying to do is to count data with two criteria ... which is done with excel formula but now I need the vba code for the same.